# Flutter: Cannot get Storage permission in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions

Cannot get Storage permission dialog and thus cannot read and write anything in storage in Flutter.
I am using `permission_handler: ^5.1.0+1` package.and have added read/write permissions in AndroidManifest.
my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` is like this:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.materialstock">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <application
        android:label="materialstock"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and my flutter code goes like this:-

```
FlatButton(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
                  child: Text('Grant Request'),
                ),
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () async {
                  bool req = await Permission.storage.request().isGranted;
                  print(req);
                },
              )
```

and I get this Error-

```
D/permissions_handler( 6106): No permissions found in manifest for: 15
I/flutter ( 6106): false
```

Comment: On an Android 10 device.

Comment: @blackapps yes android 10

Comment: Google for request legacy external storage.

Comment: I've alredy set ```android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"``` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @blackapps please help me

Comment: Why didnt you tell that? Well the error message tells us that a required permission is not found in manifest. Please elaborate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228305/discussion-between-sanket-jain-and-blackapps).

Comment: I'm updated the answer, update plugin version.

Comment: sry I am new here ,sry if I did anything wrong.which answer should be I reacting to?

Comment: @fartemlet let me try. ok? you were facing same issue?

Comment: @fartem yes its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update plugin to `^5.1.0+2` version. Check maintainer answer [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues).